# what kind of singularity $e^{\sin z}$ has at $z=\infty$

Tags: complex-analysis

Could anyone tell me what kind of singularity $e^{\sin z}$ has at $z=\infty$ ?

Enough to investigate $e^{\sin{1\over z}}$ at $z=0$

But $\lim_{z\to 0}$ the limit is $\infty$ and sometimes 0?

so essential singularity ?

Comment: your reasoning is perfectly OK. You can also notice $e^{\sin z}$ is entire and not a polynomial (though one probably needs to prove that it's not a polynomial - e.g. with your method)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint
$$\exp(z)= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{z^k}{k!}$$
And 
$$\sin(z)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k \frac{z^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}$$

So 
$$\exp(\sin(\frac{1}{z}))=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k \frac{1}{z^{2k+1}\cdot (2k+1)!})^n}{n!}$$

Comment: So Bizzzzzzare expression, Pardon me! tell me something interesting from your expression, I am waiting for a surprise

Comment: @miosaki if you multiply it out you have the laurentseries of $\exp(\sin(\frac{1}{z}))$. A singularity is essential when there iare infinite many $\frac{1}{z^k}$ terms with non zero coefficients. This is here obviously the case

Comment: Not so obvious how it's different from $$\exp(\ln(1-1/z)) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{\left(-\sum_{k=0}^\infty t^k/k\right)^n}{n!}$$

Answer (score 3):

If it's an isolated singularity, and not removable, and not a pole, there's only one possibility left...